# What is the meaning of とか in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

What is the contribution of 「とか」 to the meaning of the sentence? And what is the meaning of construction 「違ってくる」?

> 漢字は一緒でも読み方**とか**が全然**違ってくる**の本当、凄いですよね。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「漢字{かんじ}は一緒{いっしょ}でも読{よ}み方{かた}**とか**が全然{ぜんぜん}**違{ちが}ってくる**の本当{ほんとう}、凄{すご}いですよね。」

「とか」 functions to give a single (or primary) example of what is being talked about.  Here that example is the 「読み方」 ("readings" or "pronunciations" of the same kanji).

「読み方とか」, therefore, means "**things such as readings/pronunciations**".

Roughly speaking, 「とか」 is the colloquial and informal version of 「など」.

Moving on...

「違ってくる」 is a common verb phrase meaning "**to come/result in a variety of patterns/styles**".

For those wondering what the 「の」 is doing there in 「違ってくるの」, it is a nominalizer.  It nominalizes the verb phrase 「違ってくる」 to use it as the grammatical subject of the sentence.  The topic marker 「って」 or 「は」 is left unsaid after the 「違ってくるの」 as this is 100% colloquial/informal speech to begin with.

> "With even the same kanji, things such as pronunciations come in a wide variety of patterns, which is really amazing, isn't it?"